# Conexión remota a BD Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un programa Java que conecta a una base de datos Mysql. La situación es la siguiente. Dentro de la misma red tengo un servidor en el cuál está alojado la base de datos, la cuál es accedido por varias pc´s dentro de la misma red. Esto lo hace sin inconvenientes.
Ahora bien, intentando acceder a esa misma bd, desde una pc que se encuentra fuera de la red(en una red distinta), me genera problemas y no me conecta a la base.
Por ahí leí que Mysql presenta este tipo de problemas con conexiones desde una red distinta, pero no logro descifrar como solucionarlo. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu cadena de conexión debe tener, en lugar de localhost, la ip de tu máquina remota. Ejemplo: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://172.10.222.233/db"; conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");`, por otra parte, la ip de la máquina desde la cual te conectas debe estar autorizada en tu servidor MySQL, sino te daré el error: `Access denied for user 'root'@'...`

Comment: Si, de hecho así lo tengo. Funciona a la perfección con hosts que forman parte de la misma red del servidor. Pero cuando quiero acceder desde un host de otra red, ahí es donde no me conecta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:
1. El usuario que usas para conectarte debe ser remoto (%), al parecer ya está así por eso puedes acceder en la misma red (LAN).
2. Si vas a acceder de otra red, debes abrir el puerto 3306 en el router que administra la red donde se encuentra tu servidor y direccionarlo a la IP de este.
3. En el server debes abrir el mismo puerto en reglas de entrada del Firewall.

> Te recomiendo hacer esos pasos y probar la conexión con una aplicación cliente, te recomiendo el SQLYog.
>   Si el SQLYog, logra conectar, ahora debes buscar el error en el código JAVA.